# Referenced method is not found in subject class no PHPSTORM

Tags: php, mysqli

No meu código, no PHPSTORM retorna que metodo `fetch_all` não foi encontrado.

```
<?php
$conn = require 'connection.php';

$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM users');

$users = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>
```

Como acabei de iniciar, esse ainda é o único código na página, fora o HTML.

E esse é o erro que mostra no navegador:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on integer in C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\estudosphp\crud\index.php:4
```

Códiigo da página connection.php:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_mysql');

if($conn-> connect_errno){
    die('falhou a conexão ('. $conn -> connect_errno .')' . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Poste o código de "connection.php", por favor

Comment: Postei o código.

Comment: Já tentou `fetchAll()`?

Comment: Já sim, o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: `fetchAll()` é para PDO, o que não é o caso...

Comment: Use o `fetch_assoc` direto

Comment: Se `$conn` recebe o `require`, mas o arquivo `connection.php` não retorna nada, o que deveria ser `$conn`?

Comment: Dá um `print_r($conn)`

Comment: Altere o `$conn = require 'connection.php';
` para  `require 'connection.php';` ou `require_once   'connection.php';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você fez:

```
$conn = require 'connection.php';
```

Mas o arquivo `connection.php` não possui retorno, então sua variável `$conn` não será o que você espera ser. O ideal, ao meu ver, é você definir corretamente o retorno no seu arquivo:

```
<?php  // connection.php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_mysql');

if($conn-> connect_errno){
    die('falhou a conexão ('. $conn -> connect_errno .')' . $conn->connect_error);
}

return $conn;
```

Ou, simplesmente tirar a atribuição no `require`, visto que já está definindo a variável `$conn` dentro de `connection.php`

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM users');

$users = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Veja a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php):

> Manipulando Retornos: o include retorna FALSE ao falhar e emite um aviso. **Inclusões bem sucedidas, ao menos que seja sobrescritas pelo arquivo incluído, retornam 1**. É possível utilizar a declaração return dentro do arquivo incluído para finalizar o processamento e retornar para o arquivo que o incluiu.

Ou seja, você está tentando chamar o método `fetch_all` de um inteiro 1.